# como quitar el % de un string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

Me llega un string y tengo que dividir y quitar un caracter para poder operarlo, la división esta bien pero no se como quitar el caracter %,  el `String` es "IVA 19%", gracias

```
String divisionString =  productosE.getSuccessResponse().getBody().getProducts().getProduct().get(0).getTaxClass();
String[] parts = divisionString.split("\\s+");
         
String rate = parts[1].replaceAll(?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para obtener la parte numerica y evaluarla,aplicarias el  **replace** antes de **split**

```
String cadena= "IVA 19%";

    String [] parts=cadena.replace("%","").split("\\s+");

    int factor=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el metodo `replace()` este metodo tiene dos parametros el primero sería el caracter que quieres sustituir, en tu caso el %, y el segundo sería el caracter por que quieres replazarlo, si quieres eliminar con poner "" bastaria.
EJ:

```
String string = "IVA 19%"; 
string = string.replace("%", "");
```

la salida sería "IVA 19"